# "unrecognized selector sent to instance" Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I get no errors or anything, but when I run the app it crashes.
The log I get is "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MPConcreteMediaItem imageWithSize:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14eefa3b0'".

I think the line that causes this problem is this one:

`cell?.imageView?.image = sortedResults[indexPath.row].imageWithSize(imageSize)`

because when I delete it/uncomment it, everything works fine.

`imageSize`is a CGSize var.

The whole Code:

```
let startTime: NSTimeInterval = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970
    let songsQuery: MPMediaQuery = MPMediaQuery.songsQuery()
    let songsArray: [MPMediaItem] = songsQuery.items!
    let songsNSArray : NSArray = NSArray(array: songsArray)

    let descriptor: NSSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: MPMediaItemPropertyLastPlayedDate, ascending: false)
    let sortedResults: NSArray = songsNSArray.sortedArrayUsingDescriptors([descriptor])


    let finishTime: NSTimeInterval = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970
    NSLog("Execution took %f seconds to return %i results.", finishTime - startTime, sortedResults.count)




    cell?.textLabel?.text = sortedResults[indexPath.row].title
    cell?.detailTextLabel?.text = sortedResults[indexPath.row].artist
    cell?.imageView?.image = sortedResults[indexPath.row].imageWithSize(imageSize)
```

Comment: Could you show the whole error message?

Comment: Post the full error, you're missing the integral part that answers your question. But chances are the object returned from `sortedResults[indexPath.row]` does not have a method `imageWithSize(imageSize: CGSize)` implemented.

Comment: Check my updated question

Comment: What's the type of `sortedResults`?

Comment: `sortedResults[indexPath.row]` seems to be an instance of `MPMediaItem` when you are expecting to have... ?

Comment: It´s a NSArray @TimVermeulen

Comment: I added way more code to my question

Comment: You have declared that your array contains `MPMediaItem` objects.  Why do you think one of those has an `imageWithSize` function?

Comment: And that's why you shouldn't use `NSArray` in Swift.

Comment: Look how to get `MPMediaItemArtwork` from `MPMediaItem`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have added an object to your `sortedResults` `NSArray` that isn't the type you are expecting. So when you call `imageWithSize(imageSize: CGSize)` on that object the app crashes as the object doesn't respond to that selector (implement that method).

`MPMediaItem` does not implement this method. Seems that you want to access the constant values on MPMediaItem?

[General Media Item Property](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMediaItem_ClassReference/#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/General_Media_Item_Property_Keys)

Something like this may help:

```
if let mediaItem: MPMediaItem = sortedResults[indexPath.row] as? MPMediaItem {
    cell?.textLabel?.text = mediaItem.valueForProperty(MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle) as? String
    cell?.detailTextLabel?.text = mediaItem.valueForProperty(MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumArtist) as? String

    if let artwork: MPMediaItemArtwork = mediaItem.valueForProperty(MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork) as? MPMediaItemArtwork {
        cell?.imageView?.image = artwork.imageWithSize(imageSize)
    }
}
```

Long term, I'd recommend implementing one of the sorting methods on a Swift array rather than hard converting to an NSArray to sort using a descriptor - this bug would have been caught at compile time instead. Haven't checked, but something like this to keep things in Swift:

```
songsArray.sort { (itemOne, itemTwo) -> Bool in
    return itemOne.lastPlayedDate?.laterDate(itemTwo.lastPlayedDate!) == itemOne.lastPlayedDate
}
```

Comment: Okay I think I understand what the problem is. But how can I use `MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork` correct? NSArray has no member of type `.valueforproperty`

Comment: You shouldn't be calling .valueForProperty on the array. You need to extract the MPMediaItem out of the array, using `if let mediaItem: MPMediaItem = sortedResults[indexPath.row] as? MPMediaItem`

Comment: Okay great, thank you! Just to make your answer perfect for future viewers, i would suggest to edit it: Add `as? String` at the end of the lines for `textLabel`and `detailTextLabel`

Comment: I've added a snippet at the end that would enable you to keep your code with Swift types - haven't tested, but worth you looking at to prevent issues like this in future.

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing object located in sortedResults[indexPath.row] is not what you think it is, and hence it has not got the method `imageWithSize()`. Object may be nil?

**EDIT**

To be safe, you could do something like this before using the object in the array:

```
if let validObject = sortedResults[indexPath.row] as MPConcreteMediaItem? {
   // Can now use validObject safely, since we have checked that it is in fact an instance of MPConcreteMediaItem
}
```